# Data disappears after adding (MPAndroidChart)

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

After I add a new Entry to my chart, if I go to a different activity, the data point disappears when I return. How do I fix it so that the data set is saved and remembers the new data entered by the user?

Comment: Can you expand, adding some code and more context?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create arraylist of values on class level and update that whenever you get value to add then when you call onResume() you need to set these values to your dataset and invalidate your chartview.